# how to turn a linked list to a doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Is there a way to turn a simple linked list into a doubly linked list, with memory complexity of O(1), so that one can travel from head to tail and vice versa with n steps.(n is the number of nodes in the list).
not for homework, just a riddle that's driving me crazy...

Comment: Do you want a complexity of O(1) or O(n) ? Because O(1) complexity is, afaik, only available with arrays (constant access time) and not available for linked /double linked lists.

Comment: I think Benaya meant the space complexity of O(1). It is true that constant time complexity is impossible for linked lists.

Comment: don't care about time complexity, just memory/space. thanks

Comment: You can trivially implement a backwards move by a constant `k` steps with `k` memory slots and a worst case running time of `n`. So if you want to traverse the full list back to front, that'll be `O(n^2)` running time. (Whereas from head to tail it's `O(n)` running time.)

Comment: You really want that XBox, huh ?

Comment: duh...I got 29 but 11 won, but as i said, it drove me crazy that i couldnt solve a ridle...